# Finding the value of x(t) if I am given second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Question]

In this question, using the hint given I came to 
$$
z''(\sin t)+z'(2\cos t+\sin t\tan t)+z\sin t\cos^2 t=0.
$$

I don't know how to proceed further. I looked at the solutions and the equation they came to was 
$$
z''(\sin t\cos^2 t)+z\sin t\cos^2 t=0.
$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$$
x(t)= z(\sin t),\quad \dot x= z'(\sin t)\cos t,
$$
($z'$ denotes the derivative of $z$ with respect to its argument, $\sin t$)
$$
\ddot x(t)= z''(\sin t)\cos^2 t-z'(\sin t)\sin t;
$$
Substitute into the original equation:
$$
z''(\sin t)\cos^2 t-z'(\sin t)\sin t+z'(\sin t)\cos t\cdot\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}+z(\sin t)\cdot \cos^2 t=0
$$
$$
z''(\sin t)+z(\sin t)=0
$$
$$
x(t)= z(\sin t)= C_1\cos(\sin t)+C_2\sin(\sin t).
$$

Comment: thanks a lot:) i mistook z(sint) to be z.sin(t). Hence the trouble!